# sign of moment in buckling of column

Tags: structural-engineering

Can someone explain why the M is assigned to be anticlockwise here ?

[image: 1]
When i assign it as clockwise , i will get -P(δ -v) , which is different from the author ... 
If i do so , then , all the sign will be different 
Can i do so ? Why ?

or the second example here , i can understand that M = -Pv , since M+Pv = 0 at either end when it's in equlibrium.

P/s : I know the the sign convention of the bending moment of beam is positive when the beam upwards as shown ...

For the first example  , i gt M+P(∂-v) = 0 , so M = - P(∂-v) . 
I am not sure whether is my concept correct or not . 
[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Answer (score 2):

You choose your coordinate system with a FBD, however the different pin supports have to counteract the exerted force to be static. Typically bending moments are defined using the rights hand rule. In example 1, M is negative by convention only because of the orientation typically used. Notice the author has x as the y axis. You can also ignore all that as the anti clockwise moment is opposing the bending moment caused by P (negative, aka clockwise). It's a cut section.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. The bending moment caused by $P\delta$ is clockwise, so the bending moment reaction must be counter-clockwise to resist it. The bending equilibrium equation should be

$$\begin{gather}
\sum M_{support} = M + (-P\delta) = 0 \\
\therefore M = P\delta
\end{gather}$$

Comment: Do you mean the case2 ? buckling of column with pin support ? We can see that M = -Pv , which is M+Pv = 0 , not M-P = 0 , M =- P as you showed . Why you said that M = P ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks: Your question, as I understand it, is for the first example (cantilevered). My answer is therefore for the first example.

Comment: OK,  for  the  second  example,  why  it's  M = - Pv?

Comment: why  the  M has  same  direction  with  Pv?

Comment: do u have any idea now ?

Comment: why The force at the top of the beam would generate a counter-clockwise rotation around that point, so, by definition, it's negative ????? For beam , we define the moment when the beam curve downards(U) is positive , right ? So , same principles applied here . So , the moment at the bottom is counterclockwise  , at the another end , to balance the counterclockwise moment , the moment has to be clockwise , right ? So , i think M (counterclockwise) = Py (clockwise) ? Is my concept wrong ? http://imgur.com/a/URArX

Comment: @kelvinmacks: Oh, woops, sorry. Brain fart. Counter-clockwise bending moment is **positive** by definition. I'll add another comment later, no time now.

Comment: are you free to help now ?